# Network traffic simulator named 'D-ITG' doesn't work

Tags: python, network-traffic, traffic-simulation

When I Run the Command `~/D-ITG-2.8.1-r1023/src/ITGPlot/ITGplot [input.dat] [number_of_the_flow]`, the terminal shows the massage as follow:

```
(base) root@scnu-go:~/D-ITG-2.8.1-r1023/src# sudo ./ITGPlot/ITGplot ../dat_file/h1send.dat
 sudo: ./ITGPlot/ITGplot：找不到命令
```

The Chinese sentence '找不到命令' means that 'can not find the command'. Is that something wrong with  ITGplot?

Is the problem about the version of D-ITG or something else?

Details of My Device: Ubuntu 20.04, Python 3.8  D-ITG Version: D-ITG-2.8.1-r1023

Comment: Does your script need `sudo` rights?

Comment: No root or sudo required ! ........ `ITGplot` is a script, line 1 =  `#! /usr/bin/octave -qf` . .... If you want to run any file as executable, please do "chmod +x file" ..... i.e. `chmod +x ITGplot`

Comment: @Knud Larsen you're right, thanks